# heroku springboot quratz prostgesql error Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_locks" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, heroku, quartz

when trying to deploy springboot quartz postgresesql in heroku faceing below error,

with this same configuration the app connects from my ide to postgrese without any issue,
any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
## QuartzProperties
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=5
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.jdbc.schema=pw


org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'quartzScheduler'; nested exception is org.springframework.scheduling.SchedulingException: Could not start Quartz Scheduler; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block [See nested exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block]]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_locks" does not exist
```

Comment: Are you creating the schema correctly (not locally)

Comment: @akortex , i am connecting to the same db from my ide and herko, works from ide but not in heroku